# Export Hive tables to Excel Sheet

Tags: azure, hadoop, hive, hiveql, azure-hdinsight

I have a `HDInsight Cluster` which has multiple Databases. Each database has multiple `Hive tables`.

Ex: I have Database A, B, C`.

A has hive tables `One, Two, Three.`

B has tables `Four, Five, Six`.

C has hive tables `Seven, Eight, Nine`.

How can I export them to an excel file which has three sheets A,B and C. As respective sheet has their tables in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the newest version of the HadoopOffice library which has a Hive Serde for Excel files:
https://github.com/ZuInnoTe/hadoopoffice/wiki

However, for your concrete scenario you will need to use the MR/Flink/Spark modules of this library to achieve this.